# Exists / Count in client object model

Tags: client-object-model, linq

What's a good way to perform an Exists or Count on the client object model classes?

I have list with views. I want to check if a view already exists before creating it. Tried a couple of things, but the only thing which actually seems to work is loading the entire collection and using a foreach to check each views' title. I was hoping for a neater way using Linq for instance.

Tried:

- Performing a Where on the ViewCollection and loading that with LoadQuery. But when you perform Count() on that collection, you get an error.
- performing a Load on the entire Views collection and querying that; again an error.
- performing a count and loading the result, seems to be unsupported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [ViewCollection.GetByTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.viewcollection.getbytitle) or [List.GetView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getview) method to fetch the already existing view. If the view is present, it will be returned and you wont need to create the new view.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an example of it:

```
private static bool ListViewExists()
{
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://yoursharepointsiteurl");
    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");
    ViewCollection views = list.Views;

    // Check if the view already exists
    View view = views.GetByTitle("All Items");

    try
    {
        clientContext.Load(view);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```